# Netbeans 8.0.1 does not recognize that GlassFish 4.1 is running

Tags: linux, netbeans, glassfish, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

On Linux (Gentoo) if I start GlassFish from Netbeans/Services area, the server will started, the admin site is reachable, but in Netbeans I get the following error message:

GlassFish Server 4.1 start failed.
Please check server admin user name and password properties.
Also please check the server log file for other possible causes.

and I can neither start again, nor terminate.
Any idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have exactly the same but on Mac...

Comment: Not yet, I use GF 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Well, I had the **same** **situation** but on Mac. After I updated to macOS Sierra. In my case was a block on the sites that use system proxy settings, where localhost, 127.0.0.1, are blocked.

Perhaps, your case es similar, but a proxy setting on you Linux (GENTO).

For mac this is the solution [AppServer issues from Netbeans](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7680039?start=0&tstart=0)

> **Step 1:** (Try to search for the same on Linux) *Go to system preference >Network>Select your wifi connection>Advanced>select
>   proxies tab. There check 3 options 1) Auto proxy Discovery 2)Automatic
>   Proxy configuration 3) web proxy(http)*
>
> **Step 2:** Go to Netbeans>preferences>General> select use system proxy> reload> test connection You may get connection successful.   If
>   connection gets successful, Now Clean & build your Applications in
>   netbeans and press run .

I hope this help you and give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I have been struggling with this issue from a long time on my Macbook with both Tomcat & Glassfish. Your solution worked like a charm